# Devise - how to require password if changing password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a Rails 3 app and I want to show 4 main fields:

**1**. current password

**2**. current password confirm

**3**. new password

**4**. new password confirm

*`as well as`* a bunch of other fields for the user, and I only want to require the user to enter their current password if they enter a new password.

However, I cannot find how to do this in ***Devise***.

What are the attributes of Devise to let me do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you add

```
devise :validatable
```

to your user model, Devise will automatically validate your model. The validation logic can be found at:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L53

you could also overwrite this method in your controller by simply overwriding the Devise method like so:

```
  def password_required?
    prepared? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end
```